# Conexão a db SQLITE e SELECT * FROM reciclagem_data WHERE $variavel

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

Estou a fazer um programa que permite que o user digite o ID da pessoa em questão e, posteriormente, mostra numa tabela todos os dados dele.

Até agora, tenho estes dois códigos:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="search_php.php" method="post">
            ID: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

E

```
<?php
$db = "database_arduino.db"
$name = ["name"]

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reciclagem_data WHERE personID = $name"

?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table></table>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Do que eu sei, estou a ter problemas com a conexão do PHP à base de dados SQLITE3 e, no segundo código, na linha `SELECT * FROM reciclagem_data WHERE $name`. Quero que o programa registe a variável que o utilizador digitar e depois, com essa mesma base de dados, esta ser usada para exibir os dados do utilizador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está buscando o valor de `$_POST` de forma incorreta aqui:

`$name = ["name"]`

Um exemplo de como puxá-lo:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

Usando o [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), também ajuda contra SQL injection.

---

Uma forma de conexão/query com o SQLite:

```
$obj = new SQLite3;
$obj -> open("local_do_arquivo_db");
$obj -> query("sua_query");
```

---

*Sobre usar o PDO, deve ser analisado. Seria bom pesquisar mais sobre, pois as vezes irá utilizar algo sem necessidade.*

Comment: O HTML, que está seu `form`. O `form` irá enviar os dados para seu arquivo com o script PHP. Ele irá processar e exibir o conteúdo. Isso s

Comment: Em vista você tem dúvidas bem mais simples do que está querendo fazer. Precisa conhecer ao menos como funciona o html e o php colega. Não adianta atropelar as coisas. Procure ver o básico antes, se não ficará muito difícil algo que é simples. Sugiro um curso gratuito EXTREMAMENTE bom: [CursoEmVídeo](https://www.youtube.com/user/cursosemvideo/playlists)

Comment: Mesmo assim cara, você está começando pelo final. Será complicado. Procure por xampp (serivdor php), depois disso, terá que liberar driver sqlite (php.ini) ... após isso, precisa saber o que está fazendo no html/php, se não será trabalhoso. Boa sorte. ✌️

Answer (score 1):

Para se conectar ao SQLITE você deve utilizar o PDO

```
<?php 
     // Cria uma conexão com o banco de dados indicado no caminho
     $myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:/home/example/books.db'); 

     // Para rodar uma query
     $result = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM reciclagem_data WHERE $name");
?>
```

Um exemplo para poder preencher a table após pegar o resultado:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Coluna 1</th>
        <th>Coluna 2</th>
        <th>Coluna 3</th>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
        <tbody>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['idade'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sexo'] ?></td>
        </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O problema é que aparece um erro. Cannot POST. É da $name. O que faço?

Comment: *você deve utilizar* => *você pode utilizar*